# Unable to Dual boot Ubuntu 15.10 with windows 10

Tags: dual-boot

I wasn't able to dual boot ubuntu 15.10 on my laptop Dell Inspiron 15 7000 series intel i5 processor,Nvidia Geforce GTX 960M 4GB, RAM 8GB, 256SSD.

I have downloaded Ubuntu 15.10 and I have created a bootable USB. After that restarted my computer and entered into Boot options selected USB and selected INSTALL UBUNTU. later UBUNTU screen appeared and dots are moving..... and stopped at certain point and NOthing was happening after that.
PLZ Is there anyone who can help..?

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is to use a boot repair cd.

http://sourceforge.net/projects/boot-repair-cd/?source=recommended

Make a bootable usb and boot the pendrive and click on repair(recommended).
It should work fine.

Comment: I have Installed it on computer It worked Fine. It was 4th gen processor. On my laptop problem is occurred.I have booted it correctly. My laptop is intel i5-6300HQ 6th generation quad core processor